# SOQL Query in before delete trigger not finding results

Tags: apex, soql, delete

My scenario is Object A has a field that stores ID of Object B.  If Object B is deleted, I want another field marked on Object A.  I'm not sure what I'm missing, but my SOQL Query isn't finding anything when I run the actual code.

Here is my trigger:

```
trigger SF_OppSplit on OpportunitySplit (before delete) {
OppSplitRevenueMatchCheck.checkForDelete(Trigger.old);
}
```

And here is the class:

```
public class OppSplitRevenueMatchCheck {
    public static void checkForDelete(List <OpportunitySplit> oppSplits){
        List <Revenue_Detail__c> revUpdateList = new List <Revenue_Detail__c>();
        for (OpportunitySplit oppSplit:oppSplits){
            Revenue_Detail__c rev = [SELECT Id, Opportunity_Split_Id__c
                                       FROM Revenue_Detail__c
                                      WHERE Opportunity_Split_Id__c = :oppSplit.Id];

            rev.Opt_Out__c = TRUE;
            revUpdateList.add(rev);
        }
        update revUpdateList;
    }
}
```

I know I must be missing something simple, I just can't find what.

*Also, if someone can help me re-write this with the query outside of the for loop and break it down a bit (or point to a place that does), I'd be eternally grateful.  Been having a hard time wrapping my head around maps - which I assume is what I need to use here instead.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bulkified version might be:

```
trigger SF_OppSplit on OpportunitySplit (before delete) {

    Set<Id> osIds = Trigger.oldMap.keySet();
    Revenue_Detail__c[] rds = [
            select Id
            from Revenue_Detail__c
            where Opportunity_Split_Id__c in :osIds
            and Opt_Out__c = false
            ];
    for (Revenue_Detail__c rd : rds) rd.Opt_Out__c = true;
    update rds;
}
```

But this probably won't fix your problem as it is using the same fields - have you double checked the data you are testing on to make sure `Opportunity_Split_Id__c` contains the Ids you think it does?

Comment: Thanks Keith! your question actually led me to the answer.  The field had the 15 char version of the ID instead of the 18 char, once I made the field 18 char, it was able to find the record.  Also thanks for the bulkification!